# google chrome ver. 45.0.2454.85 do not work with comodo guard32.dll ver. 8.2.0.4674

Tags: google-chrome, antivirus

On windows 7x32 with comodo internet security 8.2.0.4674 (that uses guard32.dll in %systemroot%\system32 directory) I updated google chrome to version 45.0.2454.85, but could not run it, because got error in module guard32.dll.

I was able to solve this problem only renamed guard32.dll, after that chrome runs.

I think it is bad way, especially if I will update CIS, it will place guard32.dll again and chrome do not run again.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a workaround, go to the settings of Comodo > HIPS > shellcode injections and add chrome to the exception list. That should make chrome and comodo work together again, letting you upgrade both. However, note that the chrome process is not protected from shellcode injection anymore, of course. Both the chromium team and Comodo know of the issue. Once fixed you should be able to remove exclusion again.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=527496
https://forums.comodo.com/bug-reports-cis/guard32dll-kills-chrome-45-t112785.0.html

Comment: thank you very much, these links are very useful, but I don't touch HIPS, I have used the first method proposed there, renamed chrome.exe (for example, in chrome2.exe) and it worked, it's funny and great )

Comment: That will make it break again when chrome comes with a new version. But, hey, if you want to keep renaming every new version of chrome until it's fixed, that's your choice of course. As long as it works.

Comment: oh, you are right, but there is another problem, I have not found in the HIPS settings item shellcode injections, and when I tried to run chrome I completely turned off comodo, and it didn't worked

Comment: It's in the HIPS settings completely at the bottom, at least in the latest version.

Comment: can you give a screenshot of where it is, I have the Russian version and I can't find it, thanks

Comment: Intuitive GUI's was never Comodo's best feature. ;)

Comment: Update: Comodo will fix it today as stated in the bug report on Chromium: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=527496#c19

Comment: And confirmed: http://cdn.download.comodo.com/cis/download/updates/release/inis_4020/release_notes.html

Answer (score 0):

HIPS setting is the ticket (for now I guess)
A lot of scary sounding links for fixes for this focused around viruses. Spent a few hours on those (no hits), but after this link ...tada, hips and back and running. THANKS! ...phew...

Comment: So what is the answer? What is the detailed solution?

Answer (score 0):

That didn't work for me. I used to use ZoneAlarm and had to ditch it, because it started stomping on my other legit programs like this. If Comodo doesn't issue an immediate fix, I will have to uninstall it, as well, and use something else.

Comment: see answer Brave Cobra

Comment: Check the links in my answer and see whether they offer a solution for your problem. Are you sure you have a guard32.dll as specified in the original question?

Comment: No, it does not work. This is happening on several other computers I have tried. No fixes work. I guess I have to uninstall Comodo, since it has basically become a virus, like ZoneAlarm.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling HIPS, adding exceptions, etc. does not work. Goggle Chrome will not run. I guess I have to uninstall Comodo and use something else. I have already spent half a day on this crap.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the exclusion list did work however to get chrome to run I must right click the exe or shortcut of the exe and select "Run in COMODO sandbox". Simply clicking the icon will not run chrome anymore.

Comment: in sandbox it is not run too

Answer (score 0):

Find in the COMODO Firewall HIPS section 'detect shell code injection' and follow Brave Cobra's instructions.

Comment: can you give a screenshot of where it is? I have the Russian version, I change language to English but and I can't find it too